# Sidekiq job tracking

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I have a Sidekiq worker that process and upload images to Amazon S3 using Fog, Carriervave and imagemagick. When client send a POST request to `/comments`, if all conditions are ok, I want to call the Sidekiq worker to get user submitted image and do it's job asynchronously. There is any way to check if job started in my `CommentsController` when user submitted a comment is finished or not? Because  on other endpoints where client requests comments, there will be a problem if photo submitted was not finished to be processed but carryerwave returns an invalid image_url...

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using the [sidekiq-status](https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status) gem.

Comment: That looks awesome. I will try. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Great. Also - there might be other solutions to your situation that doesn't involve querying sidekiq, for example by handling the carrywave response.